# Line chart using Nivo and React

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-react

I am relatively new to charts and trying to create a line chart using [nivo.rocks](https://nivo.rocks/line/) to display stock prices for varying time frames such as 1day, 3 months, 1 year etc. So far the results I'm getting seems to be a horizontal trending lines or random zigzags patterns versus getting relatively realistic trend pattern.

In the example below I am creating a line chart for prices ranging from 50 to 65. However the chart overall looks like its almost a straight line. And here is what I have so far

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-dream-rpp79t?file=/src/App.js

While I am able to put together a simple line chart, I am trying to figure out how to build a relatively realistic chart similar to google or robinhood where even for a given day's price fluctuations between 3-5 dollars the chart represents a relative up trend or downtrend. See below screenshot for a sample 1 day price with google as you can see even though the price fluctuated between 263 and 255 the line strokes are sharper and trending downwards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jghn.png)

I am pretty sure that I am missing some fundamental chartings concept here and wondering if anyone familiar with this can guide me here. Thanks in advance